# How to assign my own .html file to HtmlDocument type of variable in ASP.NET while scraping from other websites?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, web, web-scraping

So basically I want to style my webpage and for that I need to route my scraped data to my own html. How do I do that? From what I understand I have to assign HtmlDocument variable to my own .html file, but HOW?! I couldn't find any solution online... :(

```
[Route("scrape")]
    [AcceptVerbs("GET")]

    public async Task<List<string>> Scrape()
    {
        List<string> Datalst = new List<string>();

        HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage result = await hc.GetAsync($"https://mywebsite.com");
        Stream stream = await result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load(stream);

   /*     HtmlDocument htmlDoc = null;
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml("file.html");

        htmlDoc = doc;*/

        var MarketPrices = doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;

        if (MarketPrices == null)
            Datalst.Add("Error: no data scraped");

        else
        {
            Datalst.Add(MarketPrices.ToString());
        }
return Datalst;
     }
```

Comment: The data you scrape is just data like anything else you might do in an application. You have a wide variety of options for generating a view with the data. What framework are you using? MVC? Razor Pages? Angular/Vue/React?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be on the right track with your commented-out operation:

```
htmlDoc.LoadHtml("file.html");
```

Except that it's looking for the actual HTML string, not the name of the file.  Just read the file's string contents:

```
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(await System.IO.File.ReadAllTextAsync("file.html"));
```

---

Alternatively, since you already load the text as a stream:

```
doc.Load(stream);
```

Then you can always open your file as a stream and load that too:

```
using (Stream fs = new FileStream("file.html", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    htmlDoc.Load(fs);
}
```

---

Though, if I'm being honest, the problem statement makes little sense to me:

> I want to style my webpage and for that I need to route my scraped data to my own html

It's not clear why you want to open a local HTML file for parsing in this context.  If you have HTML that you are returning to the client from a standard web application, then presumably what you would have is an MVC View or a Razor Page or, at worst, a WebForms Page.  But none of these things would involve reading/parsing a file.

So, while this is how you would load/parse a local HTML file which is what you're asking, what you may have here is an XY Problem and for future readers I think it's worth acknowledging the possibility that this may not actually get you any closer to your goal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) And maybe you could tell me how to write out the contents of "Datalst" in "file.html"? This code is from API controller, so I have to type out the constents from Datalst to "file.html" so that I could work with the design of the website with the scraped data from API controller. Right now I cannot, because it's creating a new HtmlDocument everytime I run the app. Sorry, I am not a native english speaker so the terms I used might be a little hard to understand.

Comment: @Dziamukas: *"how to write out the contents of "Datalst" in "file.html""* - That's a separate concern entirely, unrelated to what's being asked in the question above.  You are encouraged to look into the documentation for this `HtmlDocument` class you're using.  It may have a method to write to a file, or at least to output as a string which you can then write to a file. You can also look into how to modify the data in `HtmlDocument` as needed before outputting it. But I'd like to reiterate that this is **extremely strange functionality** and doesn't at all sound like what you should be doing.